# File path is not saving after Threading function

Tags: python, variables, subprocess, python-multithreading

I am searching for files with Threading:

```
import threading
def thread(seconds):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
        for file in files:
            if file == 'Viber.exe':
                viber = os.path.join(root, file) 
                print(viber)
    print("Finish")
threading.Thread(target = thread, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()
```

And after that I need to open that path:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(viber, shell=True)
```

But I'm getting error:

```
NameError: name 'viber' is not defined
```

I don't know what to do, and how to fix it((( Please somebody help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the `viber` variable in a function, python thinks the variable is local and will delete it when the function ends.

You just need to declare `viber` as global so the function will not declare it's own variable.

```
viber = None   # declare global variable # add this line

import threading
def thread(seconds):
    global viber    # use global variable  # add this line
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
        for file in files:
            if file == 'Viber.exe':
                viber = os.path.join(root, file) 
                print(viber)
    print("Finish")
threading.Thread(target = thread, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()

###########

import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(viber, shell=True)  # use global variable
```

Comment: Tottaly the best!